# Kerberos authentication with react

Tags: reactjs, authentication, django-rest-framework, kerberos, axios

I have a react app that makes requests to our REST API server using axios.

On the REST server, we added autentication using kerberos. When we simply makes a request to that server using chrome, that authentication works fine (chrome passes the correct header with kerberos's ticket data), but when the react app app makes the request, the ticket isn't added to the request.

How can we access the ticket and send it via the react app?

NOTE: the react application is served as a static content by an apache server and communicates with a diffrent REST server.

Answer (score 0):

When you already have your ticket you can pass it in the request header "Authorization" with value "Negotiate ".

For accessing the ticket it's not clear for me in which state your react app is, in which form you have keberos integrated into it or how you want to get the ticket. For instance if you want it from the user's browser you can respond with header "WWW-Authenticate" value "NEGOTIATE" and status 401 and if the browser is configured correctly it will take care of it and return with a ticket. If you want it with your own service user you could use npm kerberos and get a ticket with the kerberosClient.

Answer (score 0):

You should use directly the fetch API, not axios.

I did a NTLM/Kerberos SSO example with React on this project.
Project : https://github.com/jlguenego/react-sso-example